# Angular Mocks install ask me for dependencies

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-mock

Sincerely I don't know what to answer ... I'm newbie in Ionic + Angular ... I'm trying to install Angular Mocks but it says about Angular version.

```
$ sudo bower install angular-mocks --allow-root
bower angular-mocks#*           cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#1.4.1
bower angular-mocks#*         validate 1.4.1 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#*
bower angular#1.4.1             cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.1
bower angular#1.4.1           validate 1.4.1 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.1
bower angular#^1                cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.1
bower angular#^1              validate 1.4.1 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#^1
bower angular#>= 1.0.8          cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.1
bower angular#>= 1.0.8        validate 1.4.1 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>= 1.0.8
bower angular#>= 1.2.23         cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.1
bower angular#>= 1.2.23       validate 1.4.1 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>= 1.2.23
bower angular#1.3.16            cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.16
bower angular#1.3.16          validate 1.3.16 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.16
bower angular#1.3.13            cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.13
bower angular#1.3.13          validate 1.3.13 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.13

Unable to find a suitable version for angular, please choose one:
    1) angular#1.3.13 which resolved to 1.3.13 and is required by ionic#1.0.0
    2) angular#1.3.16 which resolved to 1.3.16 and is required by angular-resource#1.3.16
    3) angular#>=1.0.0 <1.5.0 which resolved to 1.4.0 and is required by angular-moment#0.9.2
    4) angular#1.4.1 which resolved to 1.4.1 and is required by angular-mocks#1.4.1
    5) angular#^1 which resolved to 1.4.1 and is required by angular-slugify#1.2.0
    6) angular#>= 1.0.8 which resolved to 1.4.1 and is required by angular-ui-router#0.2.13
    7) angular#>= 1.2.23 which resolved to 1.4.1 and is required by ngCordova#0.1.17-alpha

Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json

? Answer:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`angular-mock` requires `angular`, but `angular` is not in your project. It's bundled up with the `ionic` library. This means you need version 1.3.13 -> Choose #1

Comment: Thank you Michael ... I've done it with the "!" flag and bower.json was updated and the library was downloaded to bower_components folder ... but now how can I "put" the library in "www/lib" to use them into my www app ? thank you

Comment: angular-mock is a **TEST** library - it's not supposed to put them into www/lib. It should only be referenced for unit testing. - To copy other libs into www/lib It depends on the build tool you use. Sometimes you have to edit gruntfile.js or the build will automatically copy all the references in the index.html.

Comment: This tutorial says to use it :-P  http://devdactic.com/user-auth-angularjs-ionic/   but its "mocks" no "mock" ...

Comment: I see - but still `angular-mocks` is used to fake the backend request for the tutorial and shouldn't be used in an app ;-). - Anyway to copy the lib into www/lib depends on your build script. so can't give advice how it has to be done in your project.

Answer (score 0):

please add this code in bower.json

```
"resolutions": {
 "angular": "1.2.0-rc.2"
 }
```

Comment: I have    "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.4.0"
  }   ... why downgrade ?

Comment: there is a compatibility issue you need to add compatible version,
i use these one --
AngularJS v1.3.15